# How to start using `scipy`

Tags: python, windows, numpy, installation, scipy

I have previously installed Python 3.4.2 and 3.5.2 and in both cases I can dabble in writing and testing code in Idle which gives me two windows -- a "Run" window for code, and a "Shell" window for interaction and output (sorry, not sure of the correct terminology).

Now I'd like to try out `scipy`, particularly `scipy.spatial`.

**First**, I downloaded `WinPython (WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.6Qt5.exe)` from [sourceforge.net/projects/winpython/files/](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpython/files/) but when I tried to install it, it wanted to put it in my Downloads folder (where the installer was saved, obviously) so I browsed to `Program Files` and tried to install there but I get

`Error opening file for writing
C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3\IDLE (Python GUI).exe`

Same response at `C:\Program Files (x86)\`.

**Next**, I downloaded just `scipy-0.16.1-win32-superpack-python3.4.exe` and it seemed to be successfully installed until I try to run `import scipy` in my usual "Run" window I get

`ImportError: No module named 'numpy'`.

**Third**, I retried `WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.6Qt5.exe` again, but this time accepting the default Downloads install location. This time there was a successful installation of `python-3.5.1.exe` in `Downloads`. When I ran it I chose "Repair" and eventually got "Repair was sucessful." However, when I try to run `import scipy` in my usual "Run" window I get

`ImportError: No module named 'scipy'`.

What steps am I missing? What is the easiest way for me to try using `scipy`?

Comment: Use Idle (or even better Spyder) which comes with WinPython. See https://github.com/winpython/winpython/wiki/Installation

Comment: @Dietrich: Sorry for being stupid but after reading that github installation page, I still don't know what to do. It appears to me to be full of *facts* but devoid of any *instructions*. I need a "Dummy's Guide"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have correctly installed Python, you can try using the `.whl` (wheel) files available on the LFD's website.

First, make sure you have an updated version of pip which supports the use of `.whl` files by using the following command in the terminal:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Then, download the latest versions of the `.whl` files for [NumPy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and [SciPy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) into some directory you can easily locate.

Afterwards, use the following command to install the `.whl` files you've downloaded in the necessary order:

```
python -m pip install C:/path/name-of-file.whl
```

Comment: Maybe i downloaded the wrong one (numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl) for my 64-bit Win 10, but i got `numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`

Comment: I tried again -- after updating my `pip` via `python -m pip install -upgrade pip` -- got "Successfully installed numpy-1.10.4"

Comment: And was your attempt at the installation of `SciPy` successful, or are you still receiving errors?

Comment: ... then installing SciPy was successful!