# unable to install Scipy on windows, no lapack/blas resource found error

Tags: python, windows, scipy

```
PS C:\Users\Student.Student11.000> easy_install scipy
Searching for scipy

Best match: scipy 0.18.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/f8/85/37e205d2c48a9691078bd3cd6b22237e399dc1ba049d31ba8e57da44b5be/scipy-0.
18.1.zip#md5=99127abce294eaf76eafb80ef431bb9b
Processing scipy-0.18.1.zip
Writing C:\Users\STUDEN~1.000\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-e95q4ra9\scipy-0.18.1\setup.cfg
Running scipy-0.18.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\STUDEN~1.000\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-e95q4ra9\sci
py-0.18.1\egg-dist-tmp-ihgqbvxa
C:\Users\STUDEN~1.000\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-e95q4ra9\scipy-0.18.1\setup.py:322: UserWarning: Unrecognized setu
ptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
  warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with "
c:\users\student.student11.000\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.p
y:639: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-wheels\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.10.1-sse2-32\lib
is invalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
c:\users\student.student11.000\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.p
y:1532: UserWarning:
    Atlas libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\users\student.student11.000\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.p
y:1543: UserWarning:
    Lapack libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\users\student.student11.000\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.p
y:1546: UserWarning:
    Lapack sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
Running from scipy source directory.
error: no lapack/blas resources found
PS C:\Users\Student.Student11.000>
```

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689033/how-to-start-using-scipy/35689695#35689695).

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It's even the recommend way by the scipy-devs (on windows). Compiling from the sources is a pain, even for experienced users because you need to setup C, C++, Fortran compilers and care about all that linking somehow.

Comment: Thanks sascha, it worked.